# problems with doing an API call

Tags: python, api, openweathermap

I want to do an API call using the Forecast air pollution data from this website
https://openweathermap.org/api/air-pollution

The API call of the website state that it is these:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/air_pollution/forecast?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API key}
```

Now I have a dataframe in pandas which has the longitude  and latitude of 180 cities around the world.

To collect the forecast data I gave this

```
lon= df.Longitude
lat= df.Latitude
appid= 'b0gs3g26768234d11ss6jh722ff100r8e'
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/air_pollution/forecast?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={b0gs3g26768234d11ss6jh722ff100r8e}'
r= requests.get(url)
r
r.text
```

But it always say invalid API key and my API key is activated. I don't know what I doing wrong. Could someone please help me

Comment: You will need to update your code based on the answer, however, you may also need to wait a little bit between activating your API key and using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [Python's f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) in a bad way. The url should be constructed as follows:

```
url = f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/air_pollution/forecast?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={appid}"
```

Note the `f` before the first quote sign and variables names inside the curly braces - `{appid}` instead of `{<your-app-id>}`.

Also, `lat` and `lon` should be single values of latitude and longitude, not DataFrame's columns (e.g `lat = 0.0`, `lon = 0.0`). You should iterate over the dataframe and send a request for each city (each `lat` and `lon` values pair).

To be sure that your key is active, you have to take a look at the keys list [here](https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys) (logged in) and check if the status of your key is `Active`.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to first answer, your API Key is not activated yet. I tried your key with proper url and params but it didn't work. For API Weather it takes few hours to activation starts. I had the same issue before.